# Entity Framework, Razor, DB first: Change column used for foreign key dropdown texts

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first, razorgenerator

I'm setting up a simple web with Razor controllers to use as an in-house GUI for interfacing with parts of our database. For the most part this goes smoothly, however when it comes to foreign keys, apparently the first column of the referenced table (when sorted alphabetically) becomes the default representation (i.e. what's shown in the drop down box when editing).

As an example, I have a `Campaigns` table which has a foreign key to `Companies`. There is a `Companies.Name` column which I'd like to be used when displaying `Campaigns.CompanyId`. However, Razor apparently autopicks the first available, using `Companies.AccessKey` (which is pretty unintelligible) to represent the company.

I'm looking for some way to specify which columns are used for representing a row, hopefully without altering the auto generated files.

This is driving me nuts, and although I would assume it's a common issue, for some reason my googling doesn't drum up any answers :(

Comment: Can you show us a short code how you render the drop down box?

Comment: It's auto generated. I simply create a new "MVC 5 controller with views, using Entity Framework" based on a .edmx.

Comment: But there should be somewhere a line like `@Html.EditorFor(COMPANIES)` - please show this...

Comment: `@Html.DropDownList("Fk_Company", String.Empty)`, is this what you were thinking about? There is no `EditorFor` for that field.

Comment: Any luck? I want to know the same thing.

Comment: Seems like you just have to do it by hand in the view files. In other words, every time you update your db you'll have to manually readjust your views. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not know of a way to set this from the model side, but it can be solved in the view.
Replace the

```
@Html.DropDownList("Fk_Company", String.Empty)
```

with

```
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.Company, "Company") // adapt namings to fit your needs
```

and add a partial view called `Company` to `/Views/Shared/EditorTemplates` containing something like:

```
@model Company

@Html.DropDownFor(m => m.Name, m.GetValues())
```

This gives a very simple overview of how you can define custom editor templates (works the same for display templates).
**If you name the template exactly like the type it is even picked up automatically and you may not even need to alter the generated view** (I am not shure it works automagically with the `DropDownList("Fk_Company", String.Empty)` syntax, but it does for the `EditorFor`).

Comment: Marking this as the accepted answer, since I've found no other way of dealing with this than directly changing the auto generated view files.